# How two server communicate with each other?

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, mean

I have a single page application and it has 4 servers. S1,s2,s3 and s4 and each run in different port. S1 has only one table that is `usesrs` where all the user credential will be saved for authentication. Now based on users credential I want to set guard on s2 to 4 so that in every ends point i will have some method which will check the jwt token. How can I achieved this? I mean from front end authentication will be done by server 1 but rest of the server will response if user is logged in and without jwt token server2-4 will not return any data. I believe for that I need to know how to communicate from two server. i will be glad if you let me the process.

Comment: If possible you can store the JWT in authorization header and access/verify it in other servers from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in front of your API servers another server - API gateway. This server could also validate jwt token and pass through your request to other servers. Or you should implement jwt validation on each server.